# HP QTP (VbScript): work with Java-objects (like DotNetFactory for .NET classes)

Tags: java, jvm, marshalling, qtp, interprocess

is there any way to work with Java classes in the same of similar way (create, call methods)?

QTP provide  such support for .NET classes via dotNetFactory. Is there anything like that for Java?

(Our backend app has JAva API and we want to write wrapper for that).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, here is detailed explanation:
[How to work with Java Objects](http://bytes.org.ua/2011/02/03/how-to-work-with-java-objects-from-hp-quick-test-professional-analogue-of-dotnetfactory-for-java/)